# "&" symbol breaking the messages while sending Messages to whatsApp in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, special-characters

I am sending messages to users through Nodejs. If any message contains & symbol it is breaking the message.
E.g.
Terms & condition
and here is some other text

Users accepting only Terms. The rest of the messages were not sent.

Comment: Please show some code of what you are doing (as text, not as screenshot)

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)